# Saving backup to separate partiion - will wipe data/factory reset delete this partition?

Tags: factory-reset, partitions, delete

- Rooted PIxel 2 XL.
- Running Titanium for backups.
- Considering saving (encrypted) back to separate partition.

If I am in recovery mode and do Data Wipe/Factory Reset, will this separate, "backup" partition also be wiped i.e. are all partitions wiped in a recovery mode wipe, or just some?

If the answer to the above question is, "all partitions are wiped", is there a way to modify which partitions get wiped?

Lastly - is there a custom busybox (or other app) script to do a a data wipe/factory reset quickly?

Thanks